# Microsoft Xna Basics

Tags: xna, 3d

I installed Microsoft xNA, but i m quit new to it. When i run the application i get an error message (image attached):
[image]

Does this error mean that I need 3D card in my laptop??

Please explain this

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to change the properties for your project.  Under "Properties"->"XNA Game Studio"->"Game profile:", select "Use Reach...".  The default setting is "Use HiDef", which requires a beefier video card, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your laptop's video card is not supported by DirectX.

What model video card is installed in your laptop?

Comment: Intel(R) HD. Dell Inspiron n5010

Comment: Yes then it looks like your video card isn't supported by DirectX.   Sorry about the bad new.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your laptop has a low-end integrated graphics card. You could either upgrade your laptop, or use a deskop machine (which is more likely to support XNA).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest video drivers available for your video card. I had this waring on my laptop until I upgraded my drivers (nvidia)

Answer (score -2):

Yah some hardware missing and yes I think in the error message it is saying that it couldn't find the appropriate 3d device.